# Use jq to interpret nested JSON in JSON

Tags: json, nested, eval, jq, fromjson

I'm looking to use jq to automatically resolve any field which contains json as json, example:

**Input**

```
{
  "guaranteedPrizes": "[]",
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "guaranteedPrizes": [],
}
```

Comment: Can you post a more demonstrative input, if its just a single field in an object? or more than one field?

Comment: @Inian that's exactly this, but I'd like this to happen automatically without me mentioning the field's name, realising this is asking a lot

Comment: You need to create a minimal, reproducible example and an output expected. When you mean automatically, do you mean all the fields? are your fields nested?

Comment: @Inian Huh, `fromjson` [doesn't work](https://jqplay.org/s/_9R0uj6oP6) in `map_values` for some reason (the original script was `map_values(. as $in | try fromjson catch $in)`, it doesn't work either).

Comment: Possibly due to this - https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2140 ?

Comment: Yeah, I guess..

Comment: @oguzismail https://jqplay.org/s/_9R0uj6oP6 this works, but how could we include the rest of the file back? we're missing the non json stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a generic solution, you might wish to consider `walk/1`, and for efficiency, avoid calling `fromjson` redundantly:

```
walk(if type == "string"
     then . as $x | try fromjson catch $x
     else . end)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go off the “deep end” and try evaluating fromjson recursively:

```
def deep:
  walk(if type == "string"          
           then . as $x 
           | try (fromjson | deep)
             catch $x     
           else . end);
deep
```